# MPAndroidChart PieChart position of x-values

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

Is it possible to change the `xValues` of a `MPAndroidChart` `PieChart`?`
It looks like that by default:

[image]

But i want it to look like that:

[image]

**So how can i change the position of the `xValues`?**

Comment: Hi @Mulgard...did u get any solution for this???

Comment: Hi. No. I did not implement it on myself. It is currently not possible to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is **currently not possible** to show the x-values outside the chart.
You will have to implement that feature yourself, or find some kind of workaround.